# android opengl es draw scale

Tags: android, opengl-es, scale

I have a line draw using GL10.GL_LINES between 2 points (x,y,z) and (x1,y1,z1).
Now, How can I draw a scale between the two points (markers along the line at equal interval, as well as setting values).

Thanks.

Comment: Since OpenGL is just a simple drawing API, you won't get around manually sampling the line at intermediate points and drawing small orthogonal lines at those points (maybe along with some text, which you again have to render using OpenGL's given primitives, like lines or textured quads).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if i understand your question.
If you want to draw points along the line from point A to B  then  to get the points use

```
float[] points=new float[10*3];//10  how many points you want
float sx=(x-x1)/10;  
float sy=(y-y1)/10; 
float sz=(z-z1)/10; 
int num=0;
for(int c=0;c<points.length;c+=3)
{
     points[c]=x+sx*num;
     points[c+1]=y+sx*num;
     points[c+2]=z+sx*num;
     num++;
}
```